# Download Image via Glide with rxJava

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android, android-glide

I need to download pictures (Bitmaps) via a given url. As I use Glide in my project to display the pictures I thought I could simply use their mechanism to download the pictures as well. I need to use it in a RxJava Environment and my problem is that the callback onResourceReady() is not called and of course the methods subscriber.onNext() and subscriber.onCompleted() are not getting called either.

I get an IllegalStateException (see below). I guess the call to Glide needs to be done on the main thread instead of the io thread where get() will be called. Is there a way to achieve this?

This is what id do:

```
public Observable<Bitmap> get(final String url) {
    return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Subscriber<? super Bitmap> subscriber) {
            Glide
                    .with(context)
                    .asBitmap()
                    .load(url)
                    .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                            // the method onResourceReady is not getting called
                            subscriber.onNext(resource);
                            subscriber.onCompleted();
                        }
                    });
        }
    });
}
```

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must call this method on the main thread
>   09-13 14:24:58.173 25581 25581 W System.err:    at com.bumptech.glide.util.Util.assertMainThread(Util.java:132)
>   09-13 14:24:58.173 25581 25581 W System.err:    at com.bumptech.glide.RequestBuilder.into(RequestBuilder.java:350)
>   09-13 14:24:58.176 25581 25581 W System.err:    at de.dumont.bob10.data.repository.image.ImageCloud$2.call(ImageCloud.java:53)
>   09-13 14:24:58.178 25581 25581 W System.err:    at de.dumont.bob10.data.repository.image.ImageCloud$2.call(ImageCloud.java:44)
>   09-13 14:24:58.179 25581 25581 W System.err:    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50)
>   09-13 14:24:58.180 25581 25581 W System.err:    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
>   09-13 14:24:58.181 25581 25581 W System.err:    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50)
>   09-13 14:24:58.182 25581 25581 W System.err:    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
>   09-13 14:24:58.183 25581 25581 W System.err:    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50)
>   09-13 14:24:58.183 25581 25581 W System.err:    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
>   09-13 14:24:58.184 25581 25581 W System.err:    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50)
>   09-13 14:24:58.185 25581 25581 W System.err:    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
>   09-13 14:24:58.186 25581 25581 W System.err:    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:8666)
>   09-13 14:24:58.187 25581 25581 W System.err:    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSwitchIfEmpty$ParentSubscriber.subscribeToAlternate(OperatorSwitchIfEmpty.java:79)
>   09-13 14:24:58.188 25581 25581 W System.err:    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSwitchIfEmpty$ParentSubscriber.onCompleted(OperatorSwitchIfEmpty.java:72)
>   09-13 14:24:58.188 25581 25581 W System.err:    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSwitchIfEmpty$AlternateSubscriber.onCompleted(OperatorSwitchIfEmpty.java:112)
>   09-13 14:24:58.189 25581 25581 W System.err:    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emitLoop(OperatorMerge.java:650)
>   09-13 14:24:58.190 25581 25581 W System.err:    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emit(OperatorMerge.java:562)
>   09-13 14:24:58.191 25581 25581 W System.err:    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onCompleted(OperatorMerge.java:283)
>   09-13 14:24:58.192 25581 25581 W System.err:    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$MapSubscriber.onCompleted(OperatorMap.java:94)

Comment: Have you subscribed to the `Observable` returned by `get()`?

Comment: Could you please copy where you subscribe to the get()?

Comment: Rx Observables do not execute until you subscribe to them

Comment: Also, have you checked if you receive an onError event?

Comment: I indeed get a call to onError(). I missed that totally. It is an IlleagalStateException: You must call this method on the main thread. So next question: How can I easily switch the thread there?

Comment: @Emanuel  `YourObservable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndoridScheduler.mainThread())` if you already have RxAndroid lib added

Comment: The method is only one step in a longer chain that is handled with rx. To start the chain I subscribe on Schedulers.io() and observe on the MainThread. The problem with the method get() is that it seems that the call to glide needs to be done on the MainThread. So what I need is to switch to the MainThread in the get() method to execute the glide call, then switch back to the IO-Thread to proceed with the chain. It is not a general problem of the subscription because the debugger runs into the call() method and tries to execute the glide call.

Comment: I added the exception to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it like below. Unfortunately I do not get the bitmap back but that is ok-ish for me for the moment.

```
public Completable get(final String url) {
    return Completable.create(new CompletableOnSubscribe() {
        @Override
        public void subscribe(CompletableEmitter emitter) throws Exception {
            Glide
                    .with(context)
                    .load(url)
                    .downloadOnly(2000, 2000);
            emitter.onComplete();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You should use `Completable` instead of an `Observable<Void>`.

Comment: @Saket I changed the code to use a Completable as you suggested.