# Get bitmap from url with other Api calls parallelly using glide and Rxjava in Android

Tags: android, rx-java2, rx-android

I am making two API calls parallel in the following way.

```
Single.zip(API1.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()),
                API2.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()), Bifunction())).subscribe();
```

I would want to load a bitmap from an URL and send back the bitmap. Something like this

```
Single.zip(API1.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()),
                    API2.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()), getImageBitmap(), Function3())).subscribe();
```

In the method `getImageBitmap` I am trying to return `Single<Bitmap>`. Something like this.

```
Single.create(new SingleOnSubscribe<Bitmap>() {
            @Override
            public void subscribe(final SingleEmitter<Bitmap> emitter) throws Exception {
                Glide.with(context).asBitmap().load(url)
                        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                        .error(R.drawable.ic_login_error).addListener(new RequestListener<Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Bitmap> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        emitter.onSuccess(null);
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, Object model, Target<Bitmap> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        emitter.onSuccess(resource);
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }
        }).subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```

I am not getting any results out of this. How to get Bitmap from Glide in the following approach?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46196895/download-image-via-glide-with-rxjava/46200311

Answer (score 0):

While loading the image from Glide, we should either call the `.submit()` method or `.into(...)` in order to successfully get the bitmap or load the image.